# Is there an elementary proof of the following statement?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**There can never exist an infinite sequence of consecutive integers of the form:**

```
                             XY±X±Y where X,Y∈N
```

Clarification:
An example of such an integer would be 4, as;
4=(2)(2)+2-2

Edit:
The statement was in fact disproved, but I wonder if it is possible to disprove the statement;

**There can never exist an infinite sequence of consecutive integers of the form:**

```
                             MXY±X±Y where X,Y,M∈N where M > 2
```

Comment: As far as I know, there can *never* be an infinite string of integers whatsoever *and still* be considered an integer number...and whta you wrote hardly makes any sense without more, way more explanation as to what you're trying to exrpess.

Comment: What does anything mean in this question?  Presumably by "infinite string of consecutive integers", you mean a "[sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence) of integers", though that's not particularly clear.  Also, still no idea what `XY±X±Y where X,Y∈N` means in reference to this purported sequence.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: I understand it so that every integer in the sequence is supposed to have that form (that is, there exists x,y and ++ +- -+ --)

Comment: What do you mean by "consecutive" here?

Comment: Yes  user2345215 that is how I meant the question.

Comment: Note in your update that $x=1$ in the expression $2xy\pm x\pm y$ yields one equation $y-1$, which disproves for $M \gt 1$ but not for $M\gt 2$.

Comment: Yes Ok I will change that, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=2,$ then we have $2y\pm2\pm y$ which is four equations, one of which is $y-2$.  Taking $y\in[3,\infty)$ we have the set of natural numbers $\{1,2,3,\dots\}$.

Note that the same is true (that there is an infinite sequence of consecutive integers of this form) for the expression $2xy\pm x\pm y$ but not (or at least, not proven) for $3xy\pm x\pm y$ and also not for $xy+x+y, x,y\in\Bbb N.$  This last expression yields only composite numbers (subtract $1$) and it is useful as an equation form of a sieve for the prime numbers.

Edit:

To follow along with the updated question, consider the following construction:

$$\begin{align}ak\pm 1&=(ax\pm 1)(ay\pm 1)\\
&=a^2xy\pm ax\pm ay\mp 1\\
\implies k&=axy\pm x\pm y
\end{align}$$

When $a\in \{1,2\},$ it is possible (as in the first example) to deconstruct $k=axy\pm x\pm y$ into an equation of the form $k=x-u,$ and this obviously results in the entire set of values of $x$ being directly transferred to $k$ with a $u$ offset.  But as soon as $a\gt 2$ this simple deconstruction is no longer possible.

In fact, for $a\in\{3,4,6\}$ we get varying subsets of twin prime related numbers.  For example, when $a=6$ then every $k$ which cannot be written in the form $6xy\pm x\pm y$ is a number such that $6k-1, 6k+1$ are a twin prime pair.  This (for $a=6$) was proven by Maria Suzuki and logged in the January 2000 edition of American Mathematical Monthly.

So the updated question belongs to the realm of "open conjecture" since at least three of the $M$ values listed hinge directly upon the Twin Primes conjecture.

Comment: Ok thanks I didn't see that.